# Changing database in eclipse/hibernate project

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, data-persistence

My peristance file is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!-- provider -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>sau.se.migration.model.TGridStation</class>
        <class>sau.se.domain.model.Graph</class>
        <class>sau.se.domain.model.Role</class>
        <class>sau.se.domain.model.StationPrincipale</class>
        <class>sau.se.domain.model.StationSecondaire</class>
        <class>sau.se.domain.model.User</class>
        <class>sau.se.domain.model.Incident</class>
        <class>sau.se.domain.model.Listes</class>
        <class>sau.se.domain.model.Vip</class>
        <class>sau.se.domain.model.Feeder</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- Classes persistantes -->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" 
                /> -->
            <!-- logs SQL -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />
            <!-- connexion JDBC -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/semap?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding"
                value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="123456789" />
            <!-- Dialecte -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And I am quiet sure that it is the only configuration file in my project because I tried to put wrong password and I got the expected error on connection.

I want to change `semap` db name to any other but in vain.
Is there any other configuration that I don't know?

**UPDATE**
The real problem is that my application is still working with semap db (the old one)

Comment: I quiet don't understand your problem. But I guess Hibernate doesn't create database for you, it can created tables for you. So if you have changed the DB and you don't have your database named semap created then you will get exception. Change the database name in mysql and provide the new name in the connection url.

Comment: Please post the Exception you encounter and also verify (may sound trivial) if the database to which you want to switch exists and is reachable

Comment: @SamwiseGamgee I manually created the db

Comment: @JavaBond yes the db exists and it is reachable

Comment: @HoussemBdr ok. please post the exception stack trace

Comment: @JavaBond see the update plz, I should be more clear

Comment: Are you using Spring or similars to manage your JPA layer? Anyway, this problem has an easy fix. Just open your favourite IDE and search for the old database url in all your config files. If it doesn't appear, it must be you're deploying an old compilation.